# How can I avoid 'Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again'

Tags: python, pandas, flask, scikit-learn

I have Machine learning predictor which predicts number of rooms with price and area. When I click the predict button I get error(Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again). How can I avoid that.

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from flask import Flask, render_template, request


df = pd.read_excel('filtered.xlsx')
x = df[['area','price']]
y =df['number_of_rooms']

x_train, x_test ,y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.1)

model = LinearRegression()

model.fit(x_train,y_train)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/predict,', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    price = request.form['price']
    area = request.form['area']
    
    rooms = model.predict([[price, area]])[0] 
    
    
    return render_template('predict.html', rooms=rooms)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My html is like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>House Number of Rooms Predictor</title>
<head>
<body>
    <h1>Predict the Number of Rooms of a House</h1>
    <form action="/predict" method="post">
    <label for="price">Price:</label>
    <input type="text" id="price">
name="price"><br>
    <label for="area">Area:</label>
    <input type="text" id="area">
name="area"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Predict">
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post your full error stack trace for waitress as well as your deployment command? Also "Debug mode: on WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead." is not an error, its a warning.

Comment: Try making @app.route('/predict,', methods=['POST','GET']), as it seems you application is also making a get request

Comment: @JasonChia When I'm using waitress(if __name__ == '__main__':   
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080))  It just run and I get nothing it hangs.

Comment: @RupalShah I've tried that I get same error when I open link(TemplateNotFound
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home.html).

Comment: Have you put your html file in templates folder?

Comment: @RupalShah It is in same directory of python file what is templates folder. Could you give more detail please

Comment: create a  folder named 'templates' within your application. Put all the html files in templates folder.

Comment: @RupalShah So thanks Rupal it works. But when I click predict I get "Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." what can I do avoid this.

Comment: Edit your question to include all the relevant information about how you try to use `waitress` and full error you get. Don't post important information in the comments.

Comment: @buran It solved I had not create templates folder which I didn't know.

Comment: As you see in the error: on production you should not use the internal (of flask) webserver. It is not secure, and it doesn't provide all things browser may expect. On the few case it is ok, just redirect the stderr to a file, so that program will not hang

Comment: @RupalShah Am I also have to create predict html. Actually it's my first time with ML and html. I don't know so many aspects.

Comment: change action="{{ url_for('predict') }}" instead of action="/predict"

Comment: yes. There has to be predict.html in template folder and in tat html file, you can access your 'room' object that you have passed as context

Comment: Could you show me an html example @RupalShah i just know how to write home.html also "{{ url_for('predict') }}" it says urls must start with a leading slash it worked like "/{{ url_for('predict') }}".

Comment: As of now, you can have just normal html tags like <b> Predict Successful<b><br> {{ rooms}}. But later on you can add HTML tags alongwith Jinja2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a Templates folder for that name must be templates.